# Why would a culture use wooden cannons?

Tags: internal-consistency, technological-development, alternate-history, firearms

Why would an empire living in the medieval era with medieval Europe era technology choose to use(and continue using) wooden cannons in spite of advancements in technology and metal working?

Comment: Google it. Many results.

Comment: Amusingly enough, if the title were typed into google, instead of stackexchange, the first link would have answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only strategic advantage I can think of would be mobility. A wooden cannon (including normal ammo and metallic holdings) would be lighter to move about than it's metallic cousin. I also believe they'd also use a mixture of wooden and metal (bronze, cast iron or steel) cannons depending on the situation, the [Quaker Gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaker_Gun) would be one of these application, allowing for a regiment to seemingly bolster the strength of their unit for a cheaper price.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there's a Mythbusters [episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJgYtt99V5s) about whether it's possible to make a cannon out of wood.  They used iron bands around the barrel to ensure it didn't go Boom! till they wanted it to (and it being Mythbusters, of course it went boom).

They were able to put multiple shots through the cannon and could have continued to do it indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

It's already been [done](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wooden_cannon) almost exactly as you described.

Comment: this is more of a comment than an answer

Comment: The answer is yes they are possible because they already exist. There seemed little point in elaborating any further as that would simply be duplicating the wikipedia page unnecessarily. Something you could have discovered with a simple google search.